# how to skip a particular line in CSV file using perl based on some condition

Tags: perl, csv

```
while(my $line=<$data>)
    {
        chomp $line;
        my @fields   = split ",",$line;
        my $type = $fields[2];
        if($type eq "CHILD")
        {
        next;
        }    
        # some code
    }
```

I'm trying to skip the lines which have the 3rd column value as CHILD.. but i'm unable to do so. I'm reading data from a .csv file.

Comment: Perhaps you should give us some sample input to work with. I see nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: There's no obvious reason why that wouldn't work (for a given set of data where the third field really did have the value of `"CHILD"` and not `"CHILD "` or similar) but you should really use [a module for processing CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV).

Comment: Please edit this post to include some sample input. If it's proprietary then make up some input in the same format. I do this all the time with municipal data, including making up a fake state, ZN.

Answer (score 1):

Printing debug statements is a very Perl thing to do. Please notice

`print "DEBUG type[$type]\n";` below.

So, try the following:

```
while(my $line=<$data>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @fields = split /,/, $line;
    my $type = $fields[2];
    print "DEBUG type[$type]\n";
}
```

Please edit your original POST with the DEBUG lines...

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained your answer instead of making it a game of spot the difference.

Comment: @sputnick... This is skipping all lines containing the field value CHILD.. whereas i want to skip all lines containing the field value as exactly CHILD.. not something like CHILD_2

Comment: @PrabhaRajagopalan change the regex to /^CHILD$/ and it will only match CHILD and not any variations on that

Comment: @Prabha Rajagopalan : you don't answer me for the DEBUG line

Comment: @nickisfat `/^CHILD$/` does exactly the same thing as `eq "CHILD"`. Except for the optional newline.

Comment: @PrabhaRajagopalan Your question cannot be answered unless you show some sample input. Take a few lines of input that demonstrates your problem and add them to your question by editing it.

Comment: I consider this an ok interim answer that might be updated, after some input is posted to the OP.